Как сбросить предыдущий таймер сброса состояний при переходе на следующее состояние
Как сделать сброс предыдущего таймера sleep при переходе с одного состояния на другое.  Я пробовал и через data и по всякому реализовать, но он срабатывает каждый. То есть если пройдено 15 шагов, то там 15 уведомлений. Не успел дойти до конца спустя 10 минут, а все, поезд ухал. В силу того что я только 3 недели учусь программированию, даже не особо понимаю куда копать, что читать и где смотреть примеры, чтоб отключать предыдущие таймеры.
    @user_pvt_r.message(Max.M16, F.text)
    async def Max16(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
       if re.match(r"^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+$", message.text):
          await message.answer_photo(types.input_file.FSInputFile('md15.jpg'), caption="AnyText", reply_markup=HelpBtn(btns={"AnyButton": f"Help_Md_"})) 
          db = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
          cur = db.cursor()
          cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO MdAllM(UserID, MdAllM) VALUES({message.from_user.id}, {message.text})")
          db.commit()
          db.close()
          await state.set_state(Max.M15)
          await asyncio.sleep(600)
          db = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
          cur = db.cursor()
          cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM MdAllM WHERE(UserID = '{message.from_user.id}')")
          db.commit()
          db.close()
          await state.clear()
          await message.answer("Время ожидания превысило лимит. Чтобы начать заново нажмите /start")
      else:
          await message.answer("Пожалуйста введите число через точку")

    @user_pvt_r.message(Maxilla.M15, F.text)
    async def Max15(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
       if re.match(r"^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+$", message.text):
          await message.answer_photo(types.input_file.FSInputFile('md14.jpg') ,caption="AnyText", reply_markup=HelpBtn(btns={"AnyButton": f"Help_Md_"}))
          db = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
          cur = db.cursor()
          cur.execute(f"SELECT UserID, MdAllM FROM MdAllM WHERE UserID={message.from_user.id}")
    UserId, x = cur.fetchone()
          y = message.text
          z = float(x) + float(y)
          cur.execute(f"UPDATE MdAllM SET MdAllM = '{z}' WHERE UserID={message.from_user.id}")
          db.commit()
          db.close()
          await state.set_state(Max.M14)   
          await asyncio.sleep(600)
          db = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
          cur = db.cursor()
          cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM MdAllM WHERE(UserID = '{message.from_user.id}')")
          db.commit()
          db.close()
          await state.clear()
          await message.answer("Время ожидания превысило лимит. Чтобы начать заново нажмите /start")

Да, я знаю, хендлеры раздутые и вообще код урод, но я только учусь, дальше будет лучше) Я надесюь...

Поправь отступы для начала

Короче целый день изучал вопрос и в итоге спросил себя, а не начхать ли мне на этот таймер? пусть считает, мне ведь главное чтобы функция не выполнялась. И придумал вот такой костыль
    @user_pvt_r.message(Max.M16, F.text)
    async def Max16(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
       if re.match(r"^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+$", message.text):
          await message.answer_photo(types.input_file.FSInputFile('md15.jpg'), caption="AnyText", reply_markup=HelpBtn(btns={"AnyButton": f"Help_Md_"})) 
          db = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
          cur = db.cursor()
          cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO MdAllM(UserID, MdAllM) VALUES({message.from_user.id}, {message.text})")
          db.commit()
          db.close()
          await state.set_state(Max.M15)
          await asyncio.sleep(600)
          stf = await.get_state()
          if(stf = "Max:M15")
             db = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
             cur = db.cursor()
             cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM MdAllM WHERE(UserID = '{message.from_user.id}')")
             db.commit()
             db.close()
             await state.clear()
             await message.answer("Время ожидания превысило лимит. Чтобы начать заново нажмите /start")
      else:
          await message.answer("Пожалуйста введите число через точку")

В итоге все сработало, может кому поможет)
И как говорил классик, "если это тупо, но работает, это уже не тупо"
